# Maximo 7.6 Hide or mask multiple Security groups from two specific user

Tags: security, hide, maximo

Hoping someone can help, I need to hide three specific security groups from couple of users. I still need them to manage other groups except for the 3 specific groups.
either with an automation script or conditional expression.

Comment: You don't want them to see the groups at all, or just not be able to add people to those groups? If the latter, that's what the "authorize group assignment" feature is for.

Comment: And if the former, use an Object Data Restriction.

Comment: I preferred that they don't to see those specific groups.But if there is a solution to with authorize group assignment that would work too